# Ruby on Rails and POST with content-type: text/plain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

Hey Guys (Long time lurker)

I have a question regarding what rails is doing when i submit a POST request with a content-type of text/plain.

My problem is i am trying to submit some stuff within IE 8 via JQuery's AJAX (with XDomainRequest, which forces the content-type of text/plain) but rails is not picking up the submitted data, Here is an example Curl request with rails ie:

`curl -i https://localhost:8080/v1/auth -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d 'login=test@example.com' -d 'password=testpassword123' --insecure`

`Started POST "/v1/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-28 14:09:21 +1000
  Processing by V1::AuthController#create as */*
  ..
  Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)`

As you can see Rails is not picking up the login or the password. Here is the same curl request but with the Content Type set to x-www-form-urlencoded.

`curl -i https://localhost:8080/v1/auth -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'login=test@example.com' -d 'password=testpassword123' --insecure`

`Started POST "/v1/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-28 14:42:46 +1000
Processing by V1::AuthController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"login"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"testpassword123"}
  ....
  (0.8ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 1624ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)`

Also if i evaluate the request object i cannot see anything regarding what i am after. Am i approaching this the wrong way, or is there something i am missing entirely? thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

as you mentioned, XDomainRequests either sends a content-type of 'text/plain' or no content-type header at all. rails relies on the 'x-www-form-urlencoded' content-type header to be present to parse the POST body as form data. to handle an XDomainRequest post request with rails, you can parse the raw POST body manually.

to do this i've created a helper:

```
# correctly parses data from an IE8/IE9 XDomainRequest POST, which doesn't have a
# content type.
def cross_origin_params
  if request.content_type == 'text/plain' || request.content_type.blank?
    parsed_post_body = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(request.raw_post)
    parsed_post_body_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(parsed_post_body)
    parsed_post_body_params.deep_merge(params)
  else
    params
  end
end
```

and i reference `cross_origin_params` instead of `params` when accessing request data.